# npm run start working whereas ng serve not working

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular2-modules

I try to run angular 2 app with `ng serve` in Linux machine. It is not working. But I tried `npm run start` command. It is working fine. 
I got the following message when I tried `ng serve` command.

```
As a forewarning, we are moving the CLI npm package to "@angular/cli" 
with the next release,
which will only support Node 6.9 and greater. This package will be 
officially deprecated
shortly after.

To disable this warning use "ng set --global 
warnings.packageDeprecation=false".

You have to be inside an angular-cli project in order to use the 
generate command.
```

I'm trying this command inside the project folder also.

My package.json file as follows

```
    {
      "name": "xxxxxx",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e"
      },
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^4.1.3",
        "@angular/common": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/compiler": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/core": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/forms": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/http": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/router": "4.1.3",
        "@angular/upgrade": "4.1.3",
        "angular2-jwt": "0.2.3",
        "chart.js": "2.5.0",
        "core-js": "2.4.1",
        "moment": "2.18.1",
        "ng2-charts": "1.5.0",
        "ngx-bootstrap": "1.6.6",
        "primeng": "^4.0.0-rc.3",
        "rxjs": "5.4.0",
        "ts-helpers": "1.1.2",
        "zone.js": "0.8.11"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@angular/cli": "1.0.4",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.3",
        "@types/jasmine": "2.5.47",
        "@types/node": "7.0.22",
        "codelyzer": "3.0.1",
        "jasmine-core": "2.6.2",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.1.0",
        "karma": "1.7.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.1.1",
        "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.2.1",
        "protractor": "5.1.2",
        "ts-node": "3.0.4",
        "tslint": "5.3.2",
        "typescript": "2.3.3"
      }

}
```

I have tried `ng generate module [name]`. It also not working gives the same above message. What can be the reason for this?

Comment: Where is you `.angular-cli.json` file ?

Comment: It is in the same directory

Comment: With angular CLI , ng serve wont work , you will have to use npm run start

Comment: So if I try to generate module, what can I do? I tried ng generate module [name]. It is not working.

Comment: Try running `npm install --save angular-cli`

Comment: It shows a warning message like this `npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
`

Comment: What is the installed node version?

Comment: The node version is v7.10.0

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all, you are probably at one directory above of your angular app.

Try this

```
cd my-app
ng serve
```

Comment: I'm within the app directory. where, package.json and other files exists.

Comment: Which version of @angular/cli did you create this application with?

It seems so, your server has old angular cli which was just angular-cli.
They moved it to @angular project when they released version 1.
Make sure your server has new angular cli

Comment: angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.28.3

Comment: That's indeed old version. Try this commands in order 
"npm uninstall -g angular-cli"
"npm cache clean"
"npm install -g @angular/cli"

Comment: `Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 npm :
       Depends: node-read-package-json (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: node-request (>= 2.25.0) but it is not going to be installed
      
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
`

Comment: Faced an issue like this - https://askubuntu.com/questions/764743/unable-to-install-npm-on-ubuntu-14-04-due-to-broken-packages-error

Comment: That seems like an issue with ubuntu, not with ng.