# project definition could not be found , serve command requires to be run in an Angular project

Tags: angular

I tried to start the project as always but I find this problem blocking me. I tried with some solutions found on stack overflow but it didn't work. Any suggestion please?[image]

Comment: in terminal run comand:  npm install

Comment: already did , but always same prblm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try what the error message allready said. Remove the `node_modules` folder and the `package-lock.json` file. After that do `npm install` and try to start again.

Comment: commands to remove node_modules and package.json please

Comment: Navigatie to your project folder in your cmd and than use `rmdir /S node_modules` to remove the folder. With `del /f package-lock.json` you can delete the file. Otherwise just use the windows explorer. Should also work.

Comment: so how I can install it after ?

Comment: run `npm install` in your cmd. This will pull all necessary dependencies for the project. These are stored in the `node_modules` folder.

Comment: what I can do after that , I used ' ng serve ' and he didn"t recognize 'ng' command

Comment: Could you post your file structure? Make sure that you inside the project folder, when you try to run it. Otherwise try `npm start`.

Comment: npm start worked for me , but why ng serve didn"t want to run my project , for weeks I always start my project with ng serve , and now he even don"t regnize ng command what  happened ?

Comment: I can not awser this for sure. Take a look at this post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44692612/npm-run-start-working-whereas-ng-serve-not-working). The error could cause by a version confilct of the `@angular/cli` or something else. Import is that you can run your project.

Comment: I checked the link but there is no answer for the issue

Comment: Here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46623571/angular-ng-command-not-found/46623602) are also some suggestions. I would try to run `npm install -g @angular/cli@<your angular version>`

Answer (score 0):

Did you ensure that you are in the same directory as package.json?
If so, you can try the following update

```
ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=<WhateverVersionYouAreCurrentlyOn>
```

for instance `ng update @angular/cli --migrate-only --from=1.7.3`

My answer is based on the answer to another topic. you can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53097004/5045126)

Comment: yes ,I'm working on this project for weeks but I don"t know why he don"t  want to start today.